# how can I get datas from google analytics?

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

how can I get datas from google analytics?
[image]

I want to use php or javascript to get some data from ga, and display tables in my web page. 
but I don't know how to query dates from ga using api. Anyone tells how to do the job? or write down simple code to guide me. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's [php gdata client libary](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/php_client_lib) this should do what you ask